# Remote write to file via ssh

Tags: python

I have 2 raspberry, and I want to have python script on pi1 that will open file and write something into it. That works on pi1. But when i try to run script from pi2 via ssh, it wont write to file.

On pi1 I have a simple script that write something to *.txt file. I gave 777 to the file. The script works on pi1. Then I try to execute it from pi2. `ssh pi@pi1 'python /path/to/file.py'` ,but it doesn't write to pi1. On pi1 user is pi, on pi2 user is also pi.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Could we have a bit more detail, please?  If you're running the script on Pi1, you might be running as user "pi".  The user ID used by SSH needs to have the correct permission to write to the file.  So, what are the permissions on the file you want to write, or the directory if you are creating a file?  What is the user ID when you SSH in to Pi2?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. On pi1 i have a simple script that write something to txt file. I gave 777 to txt. Script works on pi1. 

Than i try to execute it from pi2. 
ssh pi@pi1 ‘python /path/to/file.py’  ,but it doesnt write to pi1.  

On pi1 user is pi, on pi2 user is also pi. Thanks

Comment: Are you able to make ssh from pi1 to pi2 ??? otherwise try ssh pi@ip_address_pi2 and also make sure enable ssh in pi2

Answer (score 1):

What you try to do isn't possible this way with **ssh**. You have to understand how **ssh** works. It's abbreviation means **s**ecure **sh**ell and it opens a console (shell) on the connected **pi2**. It is a software terminal and keyboard doing just the same as a monitor and keyboard direct connected to **pi2**. With this you can't simply store content to a file on **pi1** because there is no connection to it.

With **ssh** you are working on **pi2** and not on **pi1**. The latter only give you the screen and the keyboard. You can run your script on **pi2** within the ssh console and write to a file on **rpi2**. Then you have to copy it from **pi2** to **pi1** by network. There is a simple program **scp** (just made from ssh) that can do it. To copy the file from **pi2** to **pi1** from within the ssh console you can execute:

```
pi2 ~$ scp /path/to/file-on-pi2.txt pi@pi1:/path/to/file-on-pi1-now.txt
```

Or copy the same file staying on **pi1**:

```
pi1 ~$ scp pi@pi2:/path/to/file-on-pi2.txt /path/to/file-on-pi1-now.txt
```

There are other ways to have direct access to files on a remote device with network shares using **samba** or with exports using **NFS**.

Comment: So there is no way to write to pi2 from pi1?  

I have script on pi2 that writes arg to txt file. When i execute “script.py 222” it writes 222 to file.txt. That works on pi2. But when i try from pi 1: “ssh pi@pi2 ‘python path/to/script.py 222’” it wont write. For example i put print “something” in script.py and when i execute it from pi1, it shows me a print but wont weite to file.

Comment: I solved the problem. My script didnt have full path to txt.

f.open(path/to/file.txt) instead f.open(file.txt)

Comment: @DejanPesic I do not understand what you mean. You can redirect the output of a remote executed program to `stdout` and get it via ssh on the local device on `stdin`, if you mean that. But because you found the solution, please make an answer about it and accept it after two days. This will finish your question and it will not pop up again after months.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the ssh of pi1 using raspi-config

Open the terminal type

**raspi-config**

enable the ssh configuration.

Open the terminal in pi2 and Type

**ssh pi@ipaddressofpi1**

Hope this will work. Cheers

Comment: Thanks but i already have alot of working scripts, my only problem is writing to txt file. Cheers

Comment: try sudo nano filename.txt and then edit it